# R gWidgets2 addHandlerUnrealize block closing gwindow failed

Tags: r, gwidgets

Block closing of window, when click on "Cancel".

This works.

```
library(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")
## block closing of window
win <- gwindow("Window example")
addHandlerUnrealize(win, handler = function(h,...) {
            val <- gconfirm("Really close window", parent=h$obj)
            if(as.logical(val))
                return(FALSE)        # destroy
            else
                return(TRUE)        # don't destroy
        })
```

This does not work.

```
library(gWidgets2)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")
## block closing of window
win <- gwindow("Window example")
addHandlerUnrealize(win, handler = function(h,...) {
            val <- gconfirm("Really close window", parent=h$obj)
            if(as.logical(val))
                return(FALSE)        # destroy
            else
                return(TRUE)        # don't destroy
        })
```

I used a tryCatch({}) inside the addHandlerUnrealize, the return error message says:

(Rterm.exe:12636): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_view_unref_tree_helper: assertion `node != NULL' failed

Comment: Hmm, I don't see this error. It could come if there were a `gtable` or `gtree` object drawn that uses an underlying gtk_tree_view. What os are you on? I did see that cancel closed the window in gWidgets2 and ok did not, so I pushed a fix to github for that.

Comment: I am running on Windows 64bit, Eclipse, StatET, R 3.1.0.

Comment: @jverzani, how does github work? Do I need to download a fix from there, or just run update.packages() in R? Thank you.

Comment: @jverzani Try this: obj <- gdf(mtcars, container=gwindow("mtcars"))

Comment: These errors are not fatal, they get trapped somewhere along the way, so basically are warnings. I'm not sure where they originate, as I can't always replicate (as with this one). My guess is this happens when the table is cleaned up as the window is destroyed. As for github, if you install `devtools` (a bit of a pain on windows, but not too terrible), you can then install packages directly from github (bypassing CRAN) with `install_packages(pkgname, github_username)`. This makes it easy to push small changes to users without overwhelming the CRAN maintainers with too many updates.